# How to create a docker-compose.yml file with both public and private images?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub, azure-container-service

I'm trying to create a `docker-compose.yml` file for a specific team of developers at work. I've pushed our private images up to a private registry (Azure Container Registry) and that's ok/working :)

Next I'm trying to test out how to get the dev's of this particular team to run the `docker-compose` file which will pull down all the images and then start them all.

I've figured out that the developers will need to do this:

```
-> docker login -u <admin username of my registry> <domain of the registry>
-> docker-compose pull
```

This pulls down my private images (from ACR the private registry), but not any images in docker hub (the public registry).

- Q1: Is it possible to mix and match?
- Q2: Is there another way to make a 'user' which is only READONLY. I've read some stuff about `service accounts` or something but it's *really* confusing and I have no idea if how to do that/if that's the right way.

Here's a snippet my sample `docker-compose` file, which contains both public and private images. Do note how I'm trying to fully qualify the image domains...

```
version: '3.5'

services:

ravendb.data:
  image: hub.docker.com/ravendb/ravendb
  expose: 
    - "8080"
  networks:
    - backend
  container_name: ravendb.data
  labels:
    - "traefik.enable=false"

accounts.api:
  image: <snip>.azurecr.io/<snip>/<snip>
  networks:
<rest all snipped>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 - Two issues, somewhat related -

1. Your Docker Hub registry FQDN is wrong in the RavenDB `image` directive - `hub.docker.com` is the human readable website, the public Docker registry resides at `registry.hub.docker.com` or `index.docker.io` (append `v1` to those uri's to get the API).
2. You don't need the full public registry FQDN to pull from the public registry - its the default, and docker commands will by default pull from there if they don't detect a FQDN in the image tag preceding the image name.

Q2 - I'm not sure how Azure Container Registry works, but I'd be astonished if you can't create a readonly user.  The normal registry is a REST based API server, and can be controlled either by setting its permissions internally or by putting a reverse proxy in-front of it with the POST/PUT/DELETE and PATCH verbs requiring a different authed user to the GET verb.