# Pull docker image from a private repo by providing user credentials in in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I pushed a docker image of a simple app (ref - https://codebabel.com/ci-gitlabci-docker/) in gitlab. Now I would like to create a docker-compose.yml where in one service I would like to pull the above  docker image and in another I would like to pull a elasticsearch server image.

But I was wondering how can I provide my credentials in docker-compose.yml to pull the image from my repository?

In one of the related question [How to create a docker-compose.yml file with both public and private images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578811/how-to-create-a-docker-compose-yml-file-with-both-public-and-private-images), I saw that I have to explicitly login to my private repo before I execute *docker-compose pull*

I was wondering, whether it is the general approach or not?

Comment: If any images are not available in your private repo (where you are logged in), I believe the docker daemon will look on docker-hub for the image ( like preference order of your local machine->private repo -> docker hub). I assume elasticsearch server image is planned to be downloaded from docker hub, you should be fine just by logging in your private repo beforehand.

Comment: @Jimmy can I add the docker login in docker-compose.yml

Comment: I seriously doubt it but can not rule it out just because I have not done anything like that.